# Dynamic date value not show in date type input box in ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I use want to get dynamically from Model date from my controller side when i edit my click on grid and appending all date in form also perfectly date show in my inspect element value. but on the screen show only current date so how can i set my dynamic date ?

This is my markup:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.workExperience.JoiningDate, 
                 "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
                 new { @name = "JoiningDate", type = "date",  @class = "form-control single-date-picker" })
```

I want to my original dynamic date display on screen

also i tried

```
$("#workExperience_JoiningDate").daterangepicker(moment('@Model.workExperience.JoiningDate').format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
$('#workExperience_JoiningDate').daterangepicker(@Model.workExperience.JoiningDate)
```

Comment: It won't show if your date format is date? instead of date format. If u are using.net core, you can use taghelper to solve this problem. If u using Mvc5, u need to use external js to solve this problem.

Comment: how can use js to bind date in my date textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You may jquery Ui

For the html element, just remove the type=date

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => @Model.Trans.TransDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

put jquery reference to you script section and here is your script for date

```
$("#Trans_TransDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Here is a link to get more information https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: but not show model date in datepicker..

Comment: Edit ur answer and show me what u did